# Spark BigQuery Connector: Writing ARRAY type causes exception: ""Invalid value for: ARRAY is not a valid value""

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

Running a Spark job in Google Cloud Dataproc.  Using the [BigQuery Connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/connectors/bigquery) to load json data output from the job into a BigQuery table.

BigQuery [Standard-SQL data types documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types) states the ARRAY type is supported.

My Scala code is:

```
val outputDatasetId = "mydataset"
val tableSchema = "["+
    "{'name': '_id', 'type': 'STRING'},"+
    "{'name': 'array1', 'type': 'ARRAY'},"+
    "{'name': 'array2', 'type': 'ARRAY'},"+
    "{'name': 'number1', 'type': 'FLOAT'}"+
    "]"

// Output configuration
BigQueryConfiguration.configureBigQueryOutput(
    conf, projectId, outputDatasetId, "outputTable", 
    tableSchema)

//Write visits to BigQuery
jsonData.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf)
```

But the job throws this exception:

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
  "domain" : "global",
  "message" : "Invalid value for: ARRAY is not a valid value",
  "reason" : "invalid"
   } ],
  "message" : "Invalid value for: ARRAY is not a valid value"
}
    at 

com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.waitForCompletionAnThrowIfUploadFailed(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:432)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.close(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:287)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryRecordWriter.close(BigQueryRecordWriter.java:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$5.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1124)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1366)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 
400 Bad Request
```

Is this a Legacy vs. Standard SQL issue?  Or is ARRAY type not supported by the BigQuery Connector for Spark?

Comment: how to handle null values with spark bigquery connector. is there any other option apart from using dataframe.na functions. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using `type=ARRAY`, try setting the `type` as you normally would but also set the key `mode=REPEATED`.

An array of strings for instance would be defined as:

```
{'name': 'field1', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'REPEATED'}
```

Comment: Perfect. Solved.  Thanks for the copy/paste code block.

Comment: how to handle null values with spark bigquery connector. is there any other option apart from using dataframe.na functions. Thanks

Comment: @Phoenix hmm I'm not sure. I recommend asking this question on SO, you probably will get better answers on this one.

Comment: It can be handled by mentioning mode as 'NULLABLE'. Now I actually need to specify both NULLABLE and REPEATED for mode. Am passing the same as "mode": ["REPEATED","NULLABLE"] which does not seem to be the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

Are these arrays of strings? Integers? I believe that using this API, you need to set the `type` to the element type, e.g. `STRING` or `INT64`, but use a `mode` of `REPEATED`. The BigQuery APIs have not yet been fully updated to use standard SQL types everywhere, so you need to use the legacy convention of type + mode instead.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/6253347/elliott-brossard . while passing the schema to create a table using json string, how can we include both "NULLABLE" and "REPEATED" for mode key. thanks

Comment: There is no such option.